# open php file with mssql server database in browser

Tags: php

How do I open my php program with MSSQL Server database on my browser? Is there another software I need to install or it can be accessed through localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Type `localhost` in your browser to see your servers settings. You can access your databases from there.